# Why does select have a slightly larger height than input[type=text]?

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out why the `select` element has a larger height than `input[type="text"]`.

I thought that `line-height` controlled the height of inline elements like `select` and `input`, but it appears to work slightly different for the `select` element.

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/Dismissile/mnBsV/

I am setting the following style:

```
input[type="text"], select {
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

I would think that the elements would behave as such:

16px + 4px + 2px (line-height + padding + border) = 22px

This is what it does for the input, but the select is doing:

18px + 4px + 2px

Where is it getting the 18px from? Why aren't they consistent? Tested this in both IE8 and Chrome 15.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I couldn't find any explicit references to how high the form elements should be but in [http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#appendix D](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-ui-3/#default-style-sheet) they do mention the default height of a select is

```
select[size] {
 appearance: list-menu;
 display: inline-block;
 height: attr(size,em);
}
```

It gets its height form the font size, whereas every other input has the same style attributes. So it is valid to have a select be a different height from all the other elements. However there is no standard that I could find to define them anyway (Note how the link says it is informative not normative).

So they are different sizes because nobody said they should be the same size.

Comment: It'd be nice if the input boxes and select boxes shared the same styling rules.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get your code to work.

The trick is to:

1. Set the `display` to `block` so that the `height` property is used.
2. Set the `box-sizing` property to `content-box`. Doing so will set the content area of the `SELECT` to the height, but keep in mind that `margin`, `border` and `padding` values will not be calculated in the width/height of the `SELECT`, so adjust those values accordingly.

**Example**

```
select {
    display: block;
    padding: 6px 4px;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:content-box;
    box-sizing:content-box;
    height: 15px;
}
```

Please see your updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnBsV/3/).

Answer (score 4):

The select components has an implicit `button` with `outset border`, the solution is use `height` and `box-sizing: border-box`.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a version of the same problem. In my context, it was enough to hard code some padding into the select element:

```
.select-element { padding-bottom: 6px; }
```

Note: The following also had the same effect but caused additional problems:

```
.select-element { height: calc(100% - 18px); }
```

With that second alternative, once a form error came in and a new `ul` element was inserted after the select element (all of which is inside a flex container), the height was no longer correct. That issue does not arise using the first option.

Hope this helps someone...