# how to make input and select look nice beside eachother with custom height?

Tags: html, css

Assume I have the [following html and style](http://jsfiddle.net/Ldftk/):

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="text"/>
    <select><option>val</option></select>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

input, select {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 3em;
    line-height: 3em;
}
```

How can I make the input and select look nice? In Firefox, the height of the select is good but the text `val` is written at the top of the select, and in webkit browsers the select's height is not changed.

Is there any way to style those select and input with a custom height to look good in most modern browsers (firefox, webkit, opera, >=IE8 maybe?) when placed side by side?

Comment: Refer these. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189668/why-does-select-have-a-slightly-larger-height-than-inputtype-text

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767612/issue-with-input-select-tag-height-in-form

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561798/same-size-widthxheight-for-input-and-select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select boxes are notoriously resistant to style changes - even if you manage to apply the look you want in one browser, it's almost guaranteed to not work in another. Don't even get me started on mobile.

A lot of people lately have been using a workaround - hide the `<select>` element, and replace it with a pure HTML structure that uses javascript to mimic the `<select>` behavior. From there, the html is much ***much*** easier to style than the native `<select>`.

There are a multitude of plugins (across most javascript libraries) that do this, but by far the best I've found is SelectBoxIt. It's extremely easy to use, has universal browser and mobile support, and provides some very advanced options. The only hitch is that it requires jQuery.

http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `padding`: http://jsfiddle.net/Ldftk/2/

Seems to sort it in my firefox, I've also never been a fan of `line-height` and removed that. However if you need it then go for it.

It's also worth noting, in my experience, on macs select lists don't appear to take any note of height, or padding unless they have some `border..` type property set.

`border: none;` or `border-radius: 0px;` for instance. Only one seems to be needed to take effect

Comment: okey, `border-radius: 0` does them make to take the height and works well for chrome/safari/webkit, nice! but in firefox on mac, the `val` is cut off horizontally in your fiddle. and `border-radius: 0` makes the select look ugly, so maybe there is a better solution for firefox?

Comment: If you increase the height, you should be able to stop it from cutting off the val. You can of course use an actual value for the border radius rather than setting it at 0, or set the `border` property

Comment: i changed the title of this not explicitly relying on the height of both elements and think I found a solution by myself with `display: table` to make them look better besides each other. thanks for the help with the height, though!

Answer (score 0):

I just got it working sort of with `display: table` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ldftk/12/):

```
#container {
    display: table;
    width: 20em;
}

input, select {
    width: 50%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

input {
    height: 3em;
}
```

the height of the select is not changed, but at least it is aligned vertically centered with the text of the input. this way the styles of the select are the regular of each brother but it looks better then not aligned vertically in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

use a good reset css and apply css individually like this

```
input[type="text"]{
/*
style goes here
*/
}

select{
/
}
```